Looking for a movie of Astronouts terraforming other planet
A group of astronaut having mission to look another planet to be colonized by humans. They're try to build greenhouse to create more oxygen and something like savannah of a simple vegetation. 
But, the planet is already colonized by a number of micro organism and bug. Many of the astronouts infected or attacked.  
They tried to go back to Earth using a damaged spacecraft and collecting sample of the planet current inhabitant for another mission of terraforming.
It's in English and I watched it around 2000's

Red Planet (2000)
You can read a detailed plot description here on Wikipedia.
You can watch the movie here:



They are trying to terraform Mars with oxygen producing algae:

"Automated interplanetary missions have been seeding Mars with
  atmosphere-producing algae as the first stage of terraforming the
  planet."
" Later, the two encounter a field of algae being eaten by the
  insects, and Burchenal pieces together what happened."

"savannah of a simple vegetation", "planet is already colonized by a number of micro organism": 

And here is a picture of the "bug":

At the end of the movie, the only survivor uses an old Russian probe left behind on Mars to go back in it to the mothership in orbit and he takes samples with him: 

"Gallagher reaches the Russian probe, finds sufficient fuel to power
  the rocket's engine, but not enough electrical power to launch the
  probe, and realizes that the only available replacement is AMEE's
  power core. In a final confrontation, Gallagher is able to lure AMEE
  into a trap and disable her using one of the probe's sample launchers,
  then takes her battery. Gallagher launches himself in the probe's
  sample-return capsule and reaches orbit where Mars-1 is waiting for
  him, and he is recovered and revived by Bowman. Gallagher becomes
  upset that four astronauts died so that he could live, but Bowman
  tells him that they didn't die for nothing. The computer is busy
  analyzing the sample of Martian insects which Gallagher brought back,
  and research on them might lead to repairing Earth itself. With a
  six-month-long trip back to Earth, the computer has plenty of time to
  analyze the insects, and Bowman and Gallagher have time to start
  pursuing a romantic relationship."

Here is Val Kilmer, the only survivor of the surface crew, and the old Russian probe, which he uses to escape from the surface back to Carrie-Anne Moss:

You can find more info and nice pictures in this review here.
